# Getting a Google API Key

Tags: javascript, google-api, api-key

How do I get a [Google API Key](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/signup.html) if I'm developing a Chrome extension (i.e., address is local)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, [you don't need one](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/key.html). I'm guessing this applies to the other Google APIs as well, just try it out!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the API key, follow these instructions:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Click the project drop-down and select or create the project for which you want to add an API key.
3. Clicking on the "NEW PROJECT", click on "CREATE" to proceed.
4. Furthermore, you need to click the menu button and select APIs & Services > Credentials.
5. On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key.
6. The new API key is listed on the Credentials page under API keys. On the following page, you can rename, copy, regenerate, delete, and restrict the created API key.